# Deploy Angular2 Webpack Starter in github pages?

Tags: angular, github, deployment, webpack

I have build an Angular2 app using Angular2 webpack starter-seed as the base.
Now i need to deploy it on github pages.

I cannot use `ng github-pages:deploy` as i am not using a cli project . and the terminal gives me error saying you have to be in a cli project to use this command .

I was following this webpage as guide but it dosent work with webpack

http://developer.telerik.com/featured/quick-angular-2-hosting-angular-cli-github-pages/

I have bundled the application and in the dist folder i have the required files

[image: Dist Files]

How do i deploy my app on github pages using like 
username.gihub.io/myproject or username.github.io]

Note:- I cannot use `ng github-pages:deploy` as i am not using a cli project . and the terminal gives me error saying you have to be in a cli project to use this command .

Please Help

Comment: Can anyone please Help i am also facing this same issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The guide that you linked has all of the instructions that you need to deploy.

> From there the Angular CLI has already done a lot of the hard work for
>   you. For instance your repo already includes a .gitignore file, which
>   includes a list of files and folders that shouldn’t be included in the
>   repository, such as node_modules. In fact, the Angular CLI also
>   already initialized a git repo, and even committed the initial set of
>   files. Therefore to get your code up on GitHub you need to register
>   that new repo using the git remote command.
>
> `git remote add origin https://github.com/USERNAME/PROJECT_NAME.git`
>
> And then push your code up with the git push command.
>
> `git push origin master`
>
> At this point your code will be up on GitHub,
>   but your hosted app will not be up on GitHub Pages yet. Luckily the
>   Angular CLI has this step automated for you as well – just run ng
>   github-pages:deploy.
>
> `ng github-pages:deploy`
>
> With this command the Angular CLI creates a
>   git branch named “gh-pages”, builds a production version of your
>   application, commits that code to the “gh-pages”, pushes the branch to
>   GitHub, and then returns you to the “master” branch so you can
>   continue with your development. It takes about 30 seconds, and is
>   every bit as seamless as it sounds.
>
> Within a few minutes your app should be up and running at
>   https://USERNAME.github.io/PROJECT_NAME for the world to see.

Are you having issues with a specific one of these instructions?

Comment: i am using the angular starter webpack seed , and when i use the ng github-pages:deploy command i get a error from the terminal saying. you have to be in a cli project to use this command . This is the reason i am not able to deploy,i had also mentioned it in the question